# Cancellation of last leg of flight, can I still fly?

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, cancellations

Due to volcano eruption the last leg of my flight, that is (Hong Kong-Manila), may well be cancelled, while my whole itinerary is (Europe-Hong Kong, Hong Kong-Manila).

Can I still fly to Hong Kong even though I will be stuck there? 
(For me it's ok, since I could visit the city or take a flight from there to different destinations.)

Or will the airlines cancel my whole trip, even though the Europe-Hong Kong route is safe?

Additional info: I bought the whole itinerary as a combined offer from Lufthansa, but the (Europe-Hong Kong) is operated by Swiss Airlines and (Hong Kong-Manila) by Philippines Airlines.

Comment: FYI: Taal volcano in the Philippines began spewing ash and steam on the 12th January. NAIA has suspended all operations until at least Monday as ash is still falling on the airport. A full on eruption is possible within hours or days.

Comment: If your flight is in the next few days, you should just call the airline immediately.

Comment: Yep, it is on 16.01.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call your airline ASAP.

It is most likely the airline will automatically rebook you on a new itinerary, which could potentially involve them moving both your Europe -> Hong Kong and Hong Kong -> Manila flights to a later date.  If you were to turn up to try and catch your original Europe -> HK flight you may well find that you no longer have a booking on that flight on that day.

If you call, they should be able to arrange whatever works best for you, which could include flying into HK on your original dates, and then MK->Manila at a later date (even if you don't end up taking that flight), or potentially re-routing you to a different final destination altogether.

If you were to cancel the final HK->Manila flight, then whether you would be allowed fly to Hong Kong would depend on your nationality and whether you hold a visa. Citizens of some countries require either a visa or an onward ticket in order to fly to Hong Kong, so if such requirements existed for you and then didn't meet them, then you would not be allowed board your initial flight.

Answer (score 2):

As [Doc](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/152138/30703) wrote, you should call your airline.

If your last leg is cancelled, they will most probably not let you fly the first leg and cancel it as well: if they let you fly to Hong Kong, they would have to provide assistance for you (pay for hotels and meals) while you're stuck there, and they most probably don't want to do that.

Airlines usually have special conditions in such situations that allow for free cancellations and changes to your flights even when they are not refundable or modifiable. Some airlines are able to handle this online directly, others may require you to call them to make changes to your booking in such cases.